# Custom dimensions scope

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I'm working on the definition of the GA model for a widget which will be installed on different sites.

I want to correlate information as the widget owner ID and the widget content ID in GA with page views and sessions.

After some reading at https://support.google.com/analytics, I discovered GA custom dimensions (CD) and custom metrics (CM).

Now I'm trying to figure out which *scope level* to use.

Based on the GA docs:

> Not every metric can be combined with every dimension. Each dimension and metric has a scope: user-level, session-level, or hit-level. In most cases, it only makes sense to combine dimensions and metrics that share the same scope.

That said, and taking into consideration the following:

- `ownerId`: variable containing the id of the client (owner) of the widget.
- `contentId`: variable containing the id of the content shown in the widget.

**What's the best way to set up custom dimensions for `ownerId` and `contentId`?** More precisely:

1. To analyse the user behavior in relation to widget owners how should the scope be set in the custom dimension? Is it a `hit`-level scope?
2. And to know the total number of sessions in relation to widget owners? should the scope be set to `session`-level? Can a `hit`-level scoped custom dimension be used in this case?
3. Do I need to set up 2 custom dimensions each one with a different scope level to achieve both analyses?
4. And what about the `contentId` custom dimension in a similar case?

Please, any comment or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks!